# SSIS error -1073548535 DTS_E_SQLTASK_ERRORASSIGINGVALUETOVAR

Tags: ssis

I have implemented a SSIS package using BIDS 2008 which has an Execute SQL task to get Max of record from a table. I am getting an error -1073548535    which I believe equates to  DTS_E_SQLTASK_ERRORASSIGINGVALUETOVAR.

I have checked the datatypes and not sure what the problem is

Following is the query

select max(PICS8Id) as PICS8Id from [dbo].[Industries]

PICS8Id is float in the database

I have mapped it to the following variable in Result Set[image]

The maxPICS8Id is of type int32. I have tried Uint32 but that doesnt work either

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the "General" tab of the same SQL Task Editor?

Comment: try `double` datatype

Comment: Thanks it worked